# Security Patch SUPEE-10888 Exception "customer not save" - Decoding failed: Syntax error

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10888

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0
After SUPEE-10888 successfully done.
if i create customer then customer successfully created but i got error

[image]

My exception log

```
2018-09-20T06:14:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Decoding failed: Syntax error
Trace: #0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php(659): Zend_Json::decode('', 1)
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(133): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(226): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->_afterLoad()
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('76667', 'customer_id')
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Observer/Session.php(67): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->loadByCustomerId('76667')
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session->synchronizePersistentOnLogin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session), 'synchronizePers...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(226): Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(349): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(300): Mage_Customer_AccountController->_successProcessRegistration(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->createPostAction()
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('createpost')
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

I debug the code and find on this file
Line : 313

> /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
catch (Exception $e) {
       Mage::log($e,null,"test.log");
       $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
       $session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
}
```

My test.log file

```
2018-09-20T06:14:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Zend_Json_Exception: Decoding failed: Syntax error in /lib/Zend/Json.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php(659): Zend_Json::decode('', 1)
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(133): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(226): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->_afterLoad()
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('76667', 'customer_id')
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Observer/Session.php(67): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->loadByCustomerId('76667')
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session->synchronizePersistentOnLogin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session), 'synchronizePers...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(226): Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(349): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(300): Mage_Customer_AccountController->_successProcessRegistration(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->createPostAction()
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('createpost')
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: Did you changed any core files before the patch?

Comment: No i can not change core file

Comment: I guess the problem is at `#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(133): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)` because **NULL** is passed to `jsonDecode`. Find out why it passes NULL. It expects a string.

Comment: I got the solution if **Remember me** enable on system > configuration > Persistent Shopping Cart  then issue is occurred and i set to No.

Comment: Great Job! Can you report this bug to magento and also post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution if Remember me enable on system > configuration > Persistent Shopping Cart then issue is occurred and i set to No.

Please check below screen shot.
[image]